# boost.python exposing members of members

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
struct A
{
    int intVal;
    char charVal;
};

struct B
{
    A* someObj;
};
```

I will want to expose `B::A::intVal`, but the following dose not work:

```
class_<B>("someClass")
    .def_readonly("var", &B::A::intVar)
    ;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I had the time to complete the answer properly below. I seems to work as expected in both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B::A::intVar` does not work because it is an ill-formed qualified-id.  I've opted to breaking apart the problem into two parts: qualified-ids and exposing member of members in Boost.Python.

---

The following code introduces two structs into the same namespace.  Thus, the qualified-id of `B::A` does not exists, as `B` does not reintroduce `A` as a nested identifier:

```
struct A
{
  int intVal;
  char charVal;
};

struct B
{
  A* someObj;
};
```

To introduce the `A` identifier in `B`, `B` either needs to:

- Contain the definition of the `A` struct.  (i.e. `A` becomes a nested struct).

  ```
  struct B
  {
    struct A // introduces B::A
    {
      int intVal;
      char charVal;
    };
    A* someObj;
  };
  ```
- Provide a typedef to `A`.

  ```
  struct A
  {
    int intVal;
    char charVal;
  };

  struct B
  {
    typedef ::A A; // introduces B::A
    A* someObj;
  };
  ```

---

To directly expose a member of a member, Boost.Python is going to need a simple helper function, such as:

```
/// @brief Helper function that returns B.someObj.intVal.
int get_b_intval(const B& self)
{
  return self.someObj->intVal;
}
```

The helper function can be exposed as the Python `B::var` readonly property.

```
namespace python = boost::python;
python::class_<B>("someClass")
  .add_property("var", &get_b_intval)
  ;
```

---

Here is a the complete example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct A
{
  int intVal;
  char charVal;
};

struct B
{
  A* someObj;
};


/// @brief Helper function that returns B.someObj.intVal.
int get_b_intval(const B& self)
{
  return self.someObj->intVal;
}

/// @brief Helper function to create a B object.
B make_B()
{
  static A a;
  a.intVal = 42;
  B b;
  b.someObj = &a;
  return b;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<B>("someClass")
    .add_property("var", &get_b_intval)
    ;

  python::def("make_B", &make_B);
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> b = example.make_B()
>>> print b.var
42
>>> b.var = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you get `B::someObj` filled in somehow, or accessing a potentially random pointer will crash your code. Given that condition, you must expose both A and B to access A through B. I tested the following code and it compiles and works as expected:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct A
{
  int intVal;
  char charVal;
};

struct B
{
  A* someObj;
};

static boost::shared_ptr<B> create_b() {
  boost::shared_ptr<B> retval(new B);
  retval->someObj = new A; //<< WARNING: leakage ahead
  retval->someObj->intVal = 3;
  retval->someObj->charVal = 'a';
  return retval;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<A, A* >("A")
    .def_readonly("intVal", &A::intVal)
    .def_readonly("charVal", &A::charVal)
    ;

  class_<B, boost::shared_ptr<B> >("B")
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(&create_b))
    .def_readonly("someObj", &B::someObj)
    ;
}
```

My personal tip: If you have access to the definition of `B`, change the access pointer from B to A to use a `boost::shared_ptr<A>`. Boost.Python can handle that gracefully and reference count that properly. In that case, your code would look like this instead:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct A
{
  int intVal;
  char charVal;
};

struct B
{
  boost::shared_ptr<A> someObj;
};

static boost::shared_ptr<B> create_b() {
  boost::shared_ptr<B> retval(new B);
  retval->someObj.reset(new A); //< no more leaks
  retval->someObj->intVal = 3;
  retval->someObj->charVal = 'a';
  return retval;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<A, boost::shared_ptr<A> >("A")
    .def_readonly("intVal", &A::intVal)
    .def_readonly("charVal", &A::charVal)
    ;

  class_<B, boost::shared_ptr<B> >("B")
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(&create_b))
    .def_readonly("someObj", &B::someObj)
    ;
}
```

Under linux, you can compile and test this module like this:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -shared -fpic test.cc -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -o test.so
```

Run Python and check your code works:

```
>>> import test
>>> b = test.B()
>>> b.someObj.intVal
3
>>> b.someObj.charVal
'a'
```